# lib directory grayed out in Visual Studio and not being pushed to Azure repository

Tags: node.js, azure-devops, http-proxy, jupyterhub

I am working on a project to deploy jupyterHub on AKS using Azure pipelines.

I had to use private custom images for hub and proxy. Then, build them using azure pipelines and save in the nexus repository. Now, the images are ready and I am able to deploy jupyterhub locally with those custom images.

There is a `lib` directory in the `configurable-http-proxy` package that I need to keep along with all the files. Somehow, when I try to push all the files related to this image on Azure 'lib' directory is getting missed.

When I looked into my Visual Studio, I see this directory is grayed out. I tried to look at `.gitignore` and `.dockerignore` but could not find lib being blocked there.

Here is a screenshot of `lib` grayed out in my Visual Studio.

[image]

This is the content that I have in `.gitignore` and `.dockerignore`.

```
npm-debug.log
node_modules
*.py[co]
*~
.DS_Store
/configurable-http-proxy
bench/env
bench/results
bench/html
coverage
dist
.nyc_output
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing .gitignore in the root of this project. I found lib\ there and got the issue fixed after removing it.